# android- can't start Daemon

Tags: android, daemon

My android studio stopped working and is putting this error

```
 The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre' but was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
```

[image: Here is the config]

I didn't change anything in the parameters.

EDIT1: it doesn't work for all my projects even after invalidate/restart cache.

EDIT2:here is my local.propreties [image: local.propreties]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have wrong Windows PATH set up for JRE. Follow this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) for better understand. Also try to check **local.properties** file in the root path in your project, if everything has correct path like in my case:

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

I thought, that you run the second adb with command console but I don't see any console opened in your screen.
If that will not help, restart Android studio or even better - invalidate cache + restart Android studio. This should help in case, you don't know, what from logic reasons could help you.

Comment: I don't have the line with  `ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle` <br/> but i don't think it is a problem in the project because all my project stopped working today , they were working just fine yesterday